# How to svn merge a list of revisions contained in a file?

Tags: svn, merge

I would like to merge in a branch 2 a quite long list of revisions from branch 1. This list is contained in a text file, like, say :

```
1
3
78
… //a long list of revisions here...
324
```

Is there an elegant solution, better than doing in my branch2 working copy :

```
svn merge -c1 -c3 -c78 … -c324 branch1
```

?

I know that I shouldn't get to this point, but life is life !

EDIT : the format of the text file can easily change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a solution with bash :

```
commande="svn merge http://svn.sfrdev.fr/sfr/applications/bol-entreprise/trunk/"; for line in $(cat ~/listOfRevs); do commande="$commande -c $line"; done;echo $commande;eval $commande
```

listOfRevs is a file containing all the revision numbers, one per line :

```
r2
r5
…
rN
```